# rails route string concat method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have routes... `foo_path`, and `foo_bar_path`. Simple helpers in a `link_to`.

In the same link, I'm trying to define 2 separate paths...

`@foo` might be of class `Foo`, or it might be of class `FooBar`. It's polymorphic. So, I'd like to build the path with some sort of `@foo.class.name.underscore` call to prepend to `_path`.

I can't send it raw with `link_to 'foo', "/#{@foo.class.name.underscore}/:id"` because I have to send some parameters with it, so only using the route helper works. Unless you know how to send params with that bugger... that'd might simplify things.

Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will infer the path name from the object type. If you pass a `Foo`  object, it will use `foo_path`. If you pass a `FooBar` object, it will use `foo_bar_path`.

```
<%= link_to 'foo', foo %>
```

Assuming `foo` is one of either a `Foo` or a `FooBar` object.

I cover this in-depth in my blog post called ["Polymorphic Routes"](http://ryanbigg.com/2012/03/polymorphic-routes/).

Comment: You are correct! Unfortunately, while dumbing down my question, some of the context was lost... I'm actually trying to link to the polymorphic object. `<%= link_to p.name, player_player_positions_path(player, position_id: p.id), data: {position: p.id}, class: 'pos', title: 'add position', remote: true, method: :post %>`

Comment: in that case... the very first `player` can also be `game_player`

Comment: @Mallanaga Sounds like what you're after is `<%= link_to 'player', [player, :player_positions] %>`

Comment: I know about that syntax as well, but hadn't thought of it for this situation! it does work nicely, but how do I add params to that?

Comment: this would become a bit easier if I would/could use a form... this really only seems to work in link_to mode...

Comment: @Mallanaga This would've been better if you stated all your requirements up front. Please do that in the future. `url_for([player, :player_positions], :some_param => some_value)`

Comment: super close, but that gives a `wrong number of arguments`. `polymorphic_path()` did the trick, though! thanks, @Bigg